# How to use to_csv function so it does not change the format of my CSV file and combines all the data into one single column?

Tags: python, pandas, database, format

I am writing a code that takes an input string from a user, checks if that input code exists within a database that contains 6 columns. If the entry exists it prints its Unique ID, but if it doesn't it asks for information on the different properties to fill in the new entry, using pandas.concat to add the entry to the DB.

It works fine all the way until the saving to the file after a new entry has been added. The file is in CSV format, but the data is divided per columns as seen in the image. I will include a raw sample of the data for the DB before and after the error occurs

[image: Original DB Format]

```
Unique ID,ICE DB Name,EC per kg,Strength,Cost,Lifespan
52bdfeb3-979f-4fcd-b4eb-6ffbda643c52,"Aggregates and sand, general UK, mixture of land won, marine, secondary and recycled, bulk, loose",0.01,0,0,0
c47ba144-190c-4ed7-84c1-423159f8af34,"Aggregates and sand, general, virgin mixture of land won and marine, bulk, loose",0,0,0,0
238416cd-fce6-47b5-9c5a-4146d4067406,"Aggregates and sand, from virgin land won resources, bulk, loose",0,0,0,0
64214af1-a2d1-4b7b-acf3-137de42de2b6,"Aggregates and sand, from virgin marine resources, bulk, loose",0.01,0,0,0
2d8e1110-577f-4b24-9276-6a0b9140036a,"Aggregates and sand, from recycled resources, no heat treatment, bulk, loose",0.01,35,10.1,10
0f39187d-ba00-451f-9016-2b0c271a407e,"Aggregates and sand, from recycled resources, with heat treatment, bulk, loose",0.12,42,17.8,15
a68a6a09-34a9-4dfa-8a42-aea458041948,"Aggregates and sand,  expanded clay, bulk, loose",0.39,0,0,0
```

But after running the function it messes up the format like this:

[image: Format after error occurs]

```
Unique ID   ICE DB Name EC per kg   Strength    Cost    Lifespan
52bdfeb3-979f-4fcd-b4eb-6ffbda643c52    Aggregates and sand, general UK, mixture of land won, marine, secondary and recycled, bulk, loose   0.01    0.0 0.0 0
c47ba144-190c-4ed7-84c1-423159f8af34    Aggregates and sand, general, virgin mixture of land won and marine, bulk, loose    0.0 0.0 0.0 0
238416cd-fce6-47b5-9c5a-4146d4067406    Aggregates and sand, from virgin land won resources, bulk, loose    0.0 0.0 0.0 0
64214af1-a2d1-4b7b-acf3-137de42de2b6    Aggregates and sand, from virgin marine resources, bulk, loose  0.01    0.0 0.0 0
2d8e1110-577f-4b24-9276-6a0b9140036a    Aggregates and sand, from recycled resources, no heat treatment, bulk, loose    0.01    35.0    10.1    10
0f39187d-ba00-451f-9016-2b0c271a407e    Aggregates and sand, from recycled resources, with heat treatment, bulk, loose  0.12    42.0    17.8    15
a68a6a09-34a9-4dfa-8a42-aea458041948    Aggregates and sand,  expanded clay, bulk, loose    0.39    0.0 0.0 0
```

This is an issue because when i try to run the code again after it gives me the error that it can't find columns with the name its looking for, i.e., 'ICE DB Name'.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid

# import the database with information on building material names, strength, cost, lifespan and embodied carbon emissions
df = pd.read_csv('building_materials_DB.csv')
print(df)

# collect inputs from the user for the building material name
# Aggregates and sand, from recycled resources, no heat treatment, bulk, loose
i_material = input("Enter the name of the material you seek to replace: ")

# Check if the input exists as a database entry already
if i_material in df['ICE DB Name'].values:
    unique_id = df.loc[df['ICE DB Name'] == i_material, 'Unique ID'].values[0]
    print(f"The input '{i_material}' already exists in the database with Unique ID '{unique_id}'.")
else:
    # Prompt the user to fill in the relevant properties to add a new entry to the database
    # generate a random unique id number of numbers and letters in the format "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" where X are the numbers and/or letters
    unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).lower()
    strength = input("Enter material strength in MPa: ")
    cost = input("Enter material cost in £: ")
    lifespan = input("Enter material lifespan in years: ")

    # Create a new entry with the generated id and user input properties
    new_entry = pd.DataFrame({
        'Unique ID': [unique_id],
        'ICE DB Name': [i_material],
        'Strength': [strength],
        'Cost': [cost],
        'Lifespan': [lifespan]})

    # Append the new entry to the database
    df = pd.concat([df, new_entry])
    df.to_csv('building_materials_DB.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
    last_row = df.tail(1)
    print("New entry added to database.")
    # print the last row
    print(last_row)
```

Comment: Show a samples of the beginning of the raw CSV files (original and created by `to_csv`) as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: I have added it now, I suspect the whole problem might be an issue of which separators I am using, but I am not sure

Comment: The original separator is a comma but you use a tab for `to_csv`. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Yup! This was indeed the issue, i did not see it until I looked at the file in raw format. When I changed to_csv to include sep=',' it works! Thank you